# Using UIBezierPath:byRoundingCorners: with Swift 2 and Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, rounded-corners

I'm using this code to make 2 corners of a button rounded.

```
let buttonPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: button.bounds,
                              byRoundingCorners: .TopLeft | .BottomLeft, 
                              cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0))
```

It throws an error:

> binary operator '|' cannot be applied to two UIRectCorner operands.

How do I use this method in Swift 2.0?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Swift 2:**

```
let buttonPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: button.bounds, 
                              byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft , .BottomLeft], 
                              cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0))
```

**Swift 3** and **Swift 4:**

```
let buttonPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: button.bounds, 
                              byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft ,.bottomLeft], 
                              cornerRadii: CGSize(width:1.0, height:1.0))
```

Answer (score 13):

In this case in swift 2.0 is required to make union of two corners. F. ex.:

```
let corners = UIRectCorner.TopLeft.union(UIRectCorner.BottomLeft)
let buttonPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: button.bounds, 
                              byRoundingCorners: corners,
                              cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0))
```

Works with **Swift 2** and **Swift 3**